# Connection refused: connect error

Tags: java, sockets, networking, serversocket, socketchannel

I am trying to send a text file from the sender to the receiver however on the sender side I get connection refused: connect. I use a localhost address on the receiver side and I manually enter it in when prompt on the sender side. The error occurs at sendChannel.connect(address) in the sender class.

Sender class:

```
public static void startProcess(){
    SocketChannel sendChannel = null;
    RandomAccessFile f = null;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    SocketAddress address = null;
    try{

        sendChannel = SocketChannel.open(); // open the channel
        //DatagramSocket socket = dChannel.socket();
        boolean validAddr = false;
        while(validAddr != true){
            try{
                System.out.println("Enter in valid server IP Address");
                address = new InetSocketAddress(scan.nextLine(),7777);
                validAddr = true;
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Invalid!");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        //System.out.println("Address: " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
        sendChannel.connect(address);


        File i = new File("./data.txt");
        f = new RandomAccessFile(i,"r");
        FileChannel fChannel = f.getChannel(); 
        ByteBuffer bBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024); //set buffer capacity to 1024 bytes
        while (fChannel.read(bBuffer) > 0) {
            //SocketAddress client = dChannel.receive(bBuffer); //receive the datagram

            bBuffer.flip(); //Set limit to current position
            sendChannel.write(bBuffer);
            //dChannel.send(bBuffer, client); //send the datagram using channel
            bBuffer.clear(); //Get ready for new sequence of operations
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("End of file reached");
        sendChannel.close();
        f.close();


    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Receiver side:

```
 public static void startProcess(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = null;
    SocketChannel chan = null;
    RandomAccessFile file = null;
    try{

        serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        //Read in a valid IP Address
        boolean val2 = false;
        int tempNum = 0;
        for (int portNUM = 7777 ;!val2; portNUM++){
            try {
                serverChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", portNUM));
                tempNum = portNUM;
                val2 =true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error!");
            }
        }

        System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
        System.out.println("Port Number: " +  tempNum);


        chan = serverChannel.accept();
        System.out.println("Connected!");
        chan.getRemoteAddress();

        file = new RandomAccessFile("./output.txt","rw");
        ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        FileChannel receiveChannel = file.getChannel();
        while(chan.read(buff) > 0){
            buff.flip();
            receiveChannel.write(buff);
            buff.clear();

        }
       // buff.put((byte)65 );
        //buff.flip();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        receiveChannel.close();
        System.out.println("End of file");

        chan.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: That port is open right? Do you have access to it via your browser?
http://localhost:7777

Comment: @Salivan I tested the port with an old program and it worked but I just clicked your link and it says the page cant be displayed

Comment: Is your sender on the same host as your receiver ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I was using the localhost incorrectly on the Receiver side. I changed it to serverChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(portNUM));